# How to replace all empty lines with characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, newline

Let's consider a string, which is given below :

```
const str = `Listen !
   Don't replace me
   or me

   , but you can replace 
   the above empty line with '&'`
```

And we have a function **parse()** which does something like this :

```
  console.log(parse(str))
```

The output will be the same, but the empty line getting replaced by '&'. I thought I could do that with regex, and I tried too but I didn't know how to target empty lines. Since if I used '\n' then every line would get replaced along with empty ones. So how can this be done ?

Comment: `.replace(/^$/gm, "&");`

Comment: a regex to target empty lines would be `^\s*$` (so just start of line and end of line divided by any number of whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = `Listen !
   Don't replace me
   or me

   , but you can replace 
   the above empty line with '&'`

let strnew = str.replace(/^\s*$/gm, "&");
console.log(strnew);
```